# Fork tree in c depending on specific parameters

Tags: c, fork

So I have to make a tree with fork that I then need to show using pstree.
The tree is based on how some parameters, here is one option: 2 0 3 0 1 0 3.
Meaning: The original process needs to fork 2 children, the left one does nothing, the right one forks 3 children. The left one and the right one do nothing, the middle one forks 1 process and that process than forks 3 more children.

This is a scheme:

> ```
>      o
>     / \
>    o   o
>       /|\
>      o o o
>        |
>        o
>       /|\
>      o o o
> ```

I have no idea on how to start this, all i have is this: (Keep in mind I don't need to hardcode)
EDIT: I dont know how to identify which child to fork on from. (How do i know which child of those 3 is the middle one?)

```
    char c; int n;
    int *array = (int*)malloc(20*sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;
    //reads the cmdline arguements
    while ((scanf("%d", &n))!=EOF) {
        array[i]=n;
        //printf("%d ", array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    //gets pid of original process and makes a string to call pstree
    int d=getpid();
    char str[50] = "pstree -c ";
    char str1[20];
    sprintf(str1, "%d", d);
    strcat(str,str1);
```

Comment: Are the forked processes supposed to do anything, or is your only goal here to have your "pstree -c " call display that tree?

Comment: The goal is only to have the original process call pstree -c (its pid) to display the tree

Comment: This is too broad - what *specific* aspect are you currently stuck on?

Comment: if i had to narrow it down, i do know how to fork a process and go down to a child, the problem i have is i dont know how to get to the child that i need to fork next, right at the start, how do i for the right one and when i do, how do i get to the middle one to fork from there on?

Comment: The forkers should wait the forkees, and the leaf processes should wait for something like 60 seconds, enough time for you to run your command.

Comment: But how do i know which one needs to fork and which one needs to wait, like after i call fork for the 3 processes with the one at lvl 2, how do i know which one of them is the middle one

Comment: is it ok then if do it like this on the first one then: for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    pid[i]=fork(); if (i==2) {
           //new for in here that will call fork 3 times
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been almost a day, not sure if the comments were helpful.
Here is a suggested implementation - I understand you want to try to do it by yourself first, so, at first are hints. And if you need some clue, have a look at the C program at the bottom.

Assumptions:

- string is made of a number of digits separated each by at least a space.
- after the end of the string, instruction is equivalent to "0 fork"
- And the limitation (at the bottom).

First, you may notice a recursive pattern (but the same algo might be developed the *iterative* way also)

- fork n times
- ask children 1 .. n to fork x1 .. xn times, while feeding them with the next operation
- each child repeats the same algorithm

**Hints**

- create two functions, one to get to the next digit in string, one to skip n digits in the string
- make a recursive function that takes 2 arguments

  - the number of forks to be performed
  - the part of the string that gives instructions for the next forks, if any, of that particular child (among all children, only one should for again)
- if no fork is to be performed, the function just wait for a minute
- if N forks have to be performed,

  - get a S which points to the string after all children of *that* call have been skipped (eg "2 0 3 4 0 0" forks twice, 0 and 3 are the number of forks to be done by the children, the 2nd child gets a S that points to "4 0 0").
  - do the N forks which children call recursively the function with the arguments (eg same example 0 and 3 for 2 forks)
  - child side, return after the recursive call
  - the parent process (*this* one) each time makes S points to the next digit, only if the child creates at least one fork.
- finally wait for all process created above

That's it.

*Limitation*: the algo suggested here assumes the operation string generates only one active branch per each group of forks - the string you provide "2 0 3 0 1 0 3" goes according to that limitation (otherwise the algo would be much harder ; for instance with "2 2 3..." you'd have 2 parallel active branches, that have their own lives and must be fed from the string! Meaning searching within the string which part to be give to depth D fork F...).

---

You should get something like (yes, my prog name is "x"), visible for about a minute via `pstree -c`

```
-bash───x─┬─x
          └─x─┬─x
              ├─x───x─┬─x
              │       ├─x
              │       └─x
              └─x
```

---

**Implementation suggestion**

- First the 2 helper functions

To get to next digit (or 0 ie '\0') is string

```
char *nextdigit(char *s) {
    while (*s && (*s<'0' || *s>'9')) s++; // skip non digits
    return s;
}
```

To skip n digits

```
char *skipndigits(int n, char *s) {
    while (n--) {
        s = nextdigit(s);
        if (*s) s++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Next is how the recursive function should be called (eg from *main()*), having *forkering()* the name of the function

```
char *op = "2 0 3 0 1 0 3";

forkering(atoi(op), op+1);
```

And finally the recursive function.

```
#define WAITING 60

void forkering(int n, char *op) {
    printf("forkering %d, with %s\n", n, op);

    if ( ! n) {
        sleep(WAITING); // no forking, wait WAITING seconds
        return;
    }

    char *nextop = skipndigits(n, op); // next op (for children)

    while(n--) {
        op = nextdigit(op);
        int nop = atoi(op);  // number of forks that child has to do
        if ( ! fork()) {
            forkering(nop, nextop);
            return;
        }
        if (nop) nextop = skipndigits(1, nextop); // only skip if non zero
        op = skipndigits(1, op); // for our children
    }

    while (wait(NULL) > 0); // wait all processes created above
}
```

As you can see the function is pretty short.

Comment: Thank you, where did you call pstree from tho, mine needs to just have 1 arm going out like this bash------x----x in between the the first and the second x